# ¿Cómo obtengo la edad con la fecha de nacimiento en formato dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: nodejs

recibo una fecha con formato DD/MM/YYYY y quiero obtener la edad:

```
let today = new Date();
let FechaNacimiento = data.Titular.FechaNacimiento;
let edad = parseInt((today.toLocaleDateString("en-GB") - FechaNacimiento) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25), 10)
```

Esto no funciona...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás restando un string con un entero. Tienes que convertir la fecha de entrada a Date Object:

```
let birthArray = "29/05/1979".split("/");
let birthday = new Date(birthArray[2], birthArray[1] - 1, birthArray[0]);
let age = (new Date() - birthday) / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
console.log(Math.floor(age));
```

Comment: Deberías considerar el caso en que el año sea bisiesto

Comment: puedes ver la edición que se hizo a tu pregunta y complementar eso. La edición fue revertida debido a que se tocó el código y eso solo te corresponde a ti.

Answer (score 0):

Debes formatear la fecha que recibes, por ejemplo en formato corto MM/DD/YYY con la función substring().

Con el nuevo formato creas un objeto Date nuevo.

```javascript
let fecha1 = new Date('MM/DD/YYYY');
let fecha2 = new Date()

let resta = fecha2.getTime() - fecha1.getTime();

let edad = Math.round(resta/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)+(6*60*60*1000)+(9*60*1000)+(9,76*1000));
```

NOTA: Un año tiene 365 días 6 horas 9 minutos y 9,76 segundos

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta puede ser valida, creo que te faltaría incluir como tomar la fecha que viene en el objeto de el usuario.